# malloc crash and _int_malloc 's first param is 0

Tags: malloc, glibc, powerpc

I meet a very stange bug that malloc crash. Please help me.

When I call __int_malloc, ar_ptr will never be NULL from source code. But BT result is _int_malloc(av=av@entry=0x0). The first param is NULL. Why?

glic version:2.18

cpu:PowerPC

gdb bt:

```
    #13 _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x0, bytes=bytes@entry=18) at malloc.c:3300
        fb = <optimized out>
        pp = <optimized out>
        nb = 24
        idx = 1
        bin = <optimized out>
        victim = <optimized out>
        size = <optimized out>
        victim_index = <optimized out>
        remainder = <optimized out>
        remainder_size = <optimized out>
        block = <optimized out>
        bit = <optimized out>
        map = <optimized out>
        fwd = <optimized out>
        bck = <optimized out>
        errstr = 0x0
        __func__ = "_int_malloc"
   #14 0x0fec80cc in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=18) at malloc.c:2869
        ar_ptr = 0x0
        victim = <optimized out>
        hook = <optimized out>
        __func__ = "__libc_malloc"
```

but glic2.18 source code:

```
void*
__libc_malloc(size_t bytes)
{
  mstate ar_ptr;
  void *victim;

  void *(*hook) (size_t, const void *)
    = force_reg (__malloc_hook);
  if (__builtin_expect (hook != NULL, 0))
    return (*hook)(bytes, RETURN_ADDRESS (0));

  arena_lookup(ar_ptr);

  arena_lock(ar_ptr, bytes);
  if(!ar_ptr)
    return 0;
  victim = _int_malloc(ar_ptr, bytes);
  if(!victim) {
    ar_ptr = arena_get_retry(ar_ptr, bytes);
    if (__builtin_expect(ar_ptr != NULL, 1)) {
      victim = _int_malloc(ar_ptr, bytes);
      (void)mutex_unlock(&ar_ptr->mutex);
    }
  } else
    (void)mutex_unlock(&ar_ptr->mutex);
  assert(!victim || chunk_is_mmapped(mem2chunk(victim)) ||
     ar_ptr == arena_for_chunk(mem2chunk(victim)));
  return victim;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at a crash? Are you setting breakpoint on `_int_malloc`? What is the context of your question?

Comment: It is a crash issue. I cannt set breakpoint on __int_malloc in advance. It is confused that why __int_malloc 's first param is NULL. From source code, it will never be NULL.